# AWS beanstalk database choice

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I tried to deploy my Django project to beanstalk (no docker). It seems to me that I can only choose AWS RDS as my database choice. Could I install PostgreSQL in the same beanstalk instance?
If so, how could I install PostgreSQL myself? Using RDS is just an additional cost for me. So, I am looking for cheap solution. Possibly SQLite3 is a solution? But I hope to use PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I install PostgresSQL in the same beanstalk instance?

Yes, you could. But this will require a bit of **"manual" setup** and it will be not-scalable nor really fault tolerant. With RDS you pay premium, but you get fully managed, highly scalable and reliable database.

But of course, not all use cases require using RDS. In this case you could install PostgreSQL on your EB instance (I assume single-instance EB environment). For this you would need to setup a number of configuration options in [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html). However, this process is not that easy as you would highly-couple your application deployments with the DB.

As a middle ground, I think it would be better to install PostgreSQL on a **separate, dedicated instance**. This way your EB instance and the DB are de-coupled, easier to manage, update, backup and scale.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have another separated instance. For security reasons, if I use a separated instance as a PostgresSQL server, could I set the database URL/Username/Password using the environment GUI provided by beanstalk? In this way, I don't need to hard-code the database URL/Username/Password in my beanstalk instance. So, it will add an extra layer of security.

Comment: `import os
if 'RDS_HOSTNAME' in os.environ:
DATABASES = {
'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
'NAME': os.environ['RDS_DB_NAME'],
'USER': os.environ['RDS_USERNAME'],
'PASSWORD': os.environ['RDS_PASSWORD'],
'HOST': os.environ['RDS_HOSTNAME'],
'PORT': os.environ['RDS_PORT'],
}
}`

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question.